# Hadoop map reduce hipi.mapreduce.BinaryOutputFormat not found

Tags: java, opencv, hadoop, mapreduce, hipi

When trying to run an job Facecount on images in a HIB, I am getting this exception. I have included hipi-2.1.0.jar in class path.

```
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:576)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:487)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:753)
```

In hadoop job log the following stacktrace printed.

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.hipi.mapreduce.BinaryOutputFormat not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$2.call(MRAppMaster.java:519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$2.call(MRAppMaster.java:499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.callWithJobClassLoader(MRAppMaster.java:1598)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.createOutputCommitter(MRAppMaster.java:499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceInit(MRAppMaster.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$5.run(MRAppMaster.java:1556)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1486)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.hipi.mapreduce.BinaryOutputFormat not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getOutputFormatClass(JobContextImpl.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$2.call(MRAppMaster.java:515)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.hipi.mapreduce.BinaryOutputFormat not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
    ... 13 more
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks hadoop is not taking you class path directory, have you try placing the hipi-2.1.0.jar into the hadoop-mapreduce/lib/ folder?

if you are using cloudera this is the location you have to place the library and it should be on all the nodes.

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/